# How to convert a list to a table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a list like this one below. The list is a flatten version of the nested JSON file

```
  array([{'content_ID_994': 'BXXXXXXXXX',
  'content_ID_995': 'BYYYYYYYYY',
  'content_ID_996': 'BZZZZZZZZZ',
  'content_ID_997': 'BAAAAAAAAA',
  'content_ID_998': 'BBBBBBBBBB',
  'content_ID_999': 'BCCCCCCCCC',
  'column A': 'value1', 
  'column B': 'value2',
  'module_1_gallery': 'N1', 
  'module_1_composite': 'F1', 
  'module_1_collection': 'P1', 
  'module_2_gallery': 'N2', 
  'module_2_composite': 'F2', 
  'module_2_collection': 'P2'}],
  dtype=object)
```

I want the array to be converted to a table so I can write it to a Database. The table structure is below

```
 ID          Column A     Column B       Modules     Gallery   Composite   Collection   
 BXXXXXXXXX  value1       value2         1           N1        F1          P1
 BXXXXXXXXX  value1       value2         2           N2        F2          P2
```

How do I process my input to get the desired table structure? Any inputs would be of great help

Comment: How do you handle content_IDs? Do you just keep the first one and use it as the ID for all rows?

Comment: y is it an array? tot it would be easier to manipulate if it was a dict?

Comment: @sammywemmy I can have it as a dict , list or array. But I dont know how to manipulate all 3 of them :-(

Comment: @Allen I want the IDs to be repeated for all rows or be in a separate table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split output to 3 DataFrames, because each of them is processing different - `df1` is reshaped by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), `df2` by [`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) columns to `MultiIndex` and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last is used cross join of all `DataFrame`s:

```
a = np.array([{'content_ID_994': 'BXXXXXXXXX',
  'content_ID_995': 'BYYYYYYYYY',
  'content_ID_996': 'BZZZZZZZZZ',
  'content_ID_997': 'BAAAAAAAAA',
  'content_ID_998': 'BBBBBBBBBB',
  'content_ID_999': 'BCCCCCCCCC',
  'column A': 'value1', 
  'column B': 'value2',
  'module_1_gallery': 'N1', 
  'module_1_composite': 'F1', 
  'module_1_collection': 'P1', 
  'module_2_gallery': 'N2', 
  'module_2_composite': 'F2', 
  'module_2_collection': 'P2'}],
  dtype=object)
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame([a[0]])

m1 = df.columns.str.startswith('content_ID')
m2 = df.columns.str.startswith('module')

df1 = df.loc[:, m1]
df2 = df.loc[:, m2]
df3 = df.loc[:, ~(m1 | m2)]
#print (df1)
#print (df2)
#print (df3)


df1 = df1.melt(value_name='ID')
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)
df2 = df2.stack(0)
```

---

```
df4 = df1.assign(a=1).merge(df3.assign(a=1).merge(df2.assign(a=1), on='a'), on='a')
df4 = df4.drop(['variable','a'], axis=1)
print (df4)
            ID column A column B collection composite gallery
0   BXXXXXXXXX   value1   value2         P1        F1      N1
1   BXXXXXXXXX   value1   value2         P2        F2      N2
2   BYYYYYYYYY   value1   value2         P1        F1      N1
3   BYYYYYYYYY   value1   value2         P2        F2      N2
4   BZZZZZZZZZ   value1   value2         P1        F1      N1
5   BZZZZZZZZZ   value1   value2         P2        F2      N2
6   BAAAAAAAAA   value1   value2         P1        F1      N1
7   BAAAAAAAAA   value1   value2         P2        F2      N2
8   BBBBBBBBBB   value1   value2         P1        F1      N1
9   BBBBBBBBBB   value1   value2         P2        F2      N2
10  BCCCCCCCCC   value1   value2         P1        F1      N1
11  BCCCCCCCCC   value1   value2         P2        F2      N2
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Actually I dont want ID column in my final table and instead want Modules . How do I alter your code for that?

Comment: @Lisa Mathew I am offline, on phone only. But you can try change `df2 = df2.stack(0)` to `df2 = df2.stack(0). reset_index()`